# Formula para obtener la funcion PAGOPRIN de Excel

Tags: excel

Estuve buscando en Internet y no pude encontrar cual es la formula que se utiliza para obtener el pagoprin de la función de Excel, me podrian decir la formula para obtener el resultado o donde lo puedo buscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te viene la formula con ejemplos

http://aseduco.com/blog1/2014/09/22/financieras-excel-la-funcion-pagoprin/